# Can't login into my macbook pro after changing the account name

Tags: osx-mountain-lion, macbook-pro

I just got a macbook pro and I am totally new to mac as I have switched from Windows, the guy at the apple store created an admin user called it "apple" with a blank password, when I returned home, I logged in normally using the blank password by just pressing enter in the password box and I wanted to change the name of the user from "apple" to my name, so I followed the steps in an article that explained how to change the Full Name and the Account Name, and I changed both but I didn't set a password yet and then later when I was trying to login again the user icon above the password box displayed the new name I've set but it doesn't accept the blank password and now I am stuck and the only option available is the cancel button at the bottom of the screen. It seems that I've done something really wrong :S

Can someone help me with this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this (even though there is no password set, there could have been some weird thing happen in the background when you changed the username) http://osxdaily.com/2011/04/25/change-admin-password-mac/

Comment: The article says reboot while holding command+S, as I said I am stuck, with the screen that have the user icon and the password box and a cancel button, how can I reboot from here?

Comment: In tiger you could type in >shutdown or >restart in the username and hit return. I haven't had to try it in Mountain Lion and my Mac is at my house. You can try that, if that doesn't work, you can always hard shut down by holding down the power button.

Comment: My problem has been solved but in a slightly different way, you see I followed the steps in the article and when I reached the step of "passwd (username)" where I placed the new username I have previously set, I got an error message so I typed the command ls /Users/ and it gave me only "apple" and not the new username so I thought of why not just reboot and see what's going to happen then when I reached the login screen I pressed enter in the password box and I was logged in successfully!!